# How to calculate lot based on account currency in Metatrader4

Tags: mql4, trading, metatrader4

I am a little bit new in this language, but I have the basics.

What I want: open a position with stop loss and take profit.

I want to place an order with 100 euro, and I want to set the stop loss to 10 euros, and set the take profit to 5 euros. But as I see the OrderSend method requires lots for placing the order, and levels for stop loss and take profit.

And my problem is: how to calculate these values based on the euro amounts I want to set?

I searched for some lot-pip-etc calculation on the web, but after all what I tried did not work. This is how I wanted to calculate:

```
double AmountToTradeInEuro = 100;
double AmountToTakeInEuro = 5;
double AmountToMaxLossInEuro = 10;
double Lots = AmountToTradeInEuro / MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_TICKVALUE);
double StopLossLevel = AmountToTakeInEuro / MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_TICKVALUE);
double TakeProfitLevel = AmountToMaxLossInEuro / MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_TICKVALUE);
OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, Lots, Bid, 3, StopLossLevel, TakeProfitLevel);
```

Basically I would like to know how to calculate the Lot for 100 euro and how to calculate the Levels for stoploss and takeprofit.

And are the stoploss and takeprofit levels also lots? Or are they different units?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MQL4!
First question is about the account currency - if it is USD (or something else not EUR) - you have to make such convertion. Ok, let me describe what to do with the EUR balance.
You can compute lot size based on the stoploss - in such a case you can get tick value using `MarketInfo(_Symbol,MODE_TICKVALUE)`. But you must know the price level where to exit (stoploss), whether it is 1 pips or 100 pips. Let us think that is 100 ticks (which is equal to 10 pips of 5-digit broker). Then, your lot size is
`double lot = AmountToMaxLoss / (MarketInfor(_Symbol, MODE_TICKVALUE) * stoploss)`, then you have to normalize the result:

`double lot_step=MarketInfo(_Symbol, MODE_LOTSTEP);
double result = lot_step * NormalizeDouble(lot / lot_step, 0);`
then check that `result > MarketInfo(_Symbol, MODE_MINLOT)`.
About takeprofit - it might be a strange approach to wait for your takeprofit target in the currency instead of the price level but if you need - the way is same.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I want to trade EUR/USD with EUR account.

My questions: what is 'stoploss'? How to calculate it based on 10 euro? 'double result' why do you devide and then multiple with the same 'lot_step'? It makes no sense.

Comment: This is a forum for programmers, not for traders or who wants to become a trader... You should figure out the question on stop loss in the forex forums. lot - I just edited, please check again

Comment: Yes I know that most of my question is not about how to program it, but I thought I can get answer here like always. Focusing on the programming side of my question: could you tell me what is the unit of stoploss and takeprofit in MQL4? Also lot? Or pip? Or they are prices?

Comment: entry and stoploss and take profit are all prices. You can compute stoploss depending on the rules - either entry minus X pips or ticks, or in per cent also. Anyway it cannot be related to balance. At the same time, the amount of money that can be lost in case of stoploss is nominated in the account balance, and is a product of lot size, tick value and amount of ticks between entry price and stoploss